# Collinear points if and only if difference of angles is 90

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, where $\angle BAC > 90^{\circ}$ let $H, O$ be the ortho-center and circumscribed center respectively. Let $K$ be a point on the line $AH$ such that $AH=AK$. Prove that $C, K$ and $O$ are collinear if and only if $\angle BAC - \angle ABC = 90^{\circ}$.

Could anybody please solve this using only Euclidean geometry... I think there is a way to solve it with isogonal conjugates but I'm searching a more elementary way to do it.

I have been trying to solve it, I realized that $A$ is the ortho-center of $\triangle BCH$ but I don't really know what to do or how to use the angle condition they gave me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your ideas about the problem?

Comment: I don't really have much... but I did it